# Can I use Avid olive and connector insert in a Shimano brake?

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake, sram

Basically, this is the question:
I can use the olives and connector inserts proper for Avid in a Shimano Deore M596 brake/hose?
Has anyone tried and can report if it worked perfectly or if there was any problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: No idea, but if you don't get a clear and well-supported answer, just spend the money to buy the right parts.  Brakes are important, and trying to economise is a bad idea.

Comment: I second that... I've never done this or seen it done and then tested over time. The conventional thinking by both manufacturers and shops is they are in no way interchangeable. And if you just look at Shimano versus Avid, the designs of the barb and olive are way different. (Avid is stepped where Shimano has a smooth bevel.)

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot.  They are not cross compatible.  Shimano Olives, hose and inserts only work with Shimano components. The same is true for Avid brake equipment.

Beyond not being designed to work together you void any warranty claim by not using compatible equipment.  You also give up any legal approach to the manufacturer if you use other company's parts.  So if you crash because the brakes failed and want to say that's Shimano's fault and it actually was.  They will say it had Avid olives and inserts on it.

Comment: Is this because you say so, or is there actual physical incompatibility?

Comment: they are literally different sizes and shapes.  Sure you could mash and jam your way to something that resembled a working solution but why?

Comment: So, maybe that could be a part of the answer. As for why, for example getting a good deal on one brand or having spare parts available when needed is good enough reason. There are lots of people on this site who claim that any mixing of brands is impossible, and often they are wrong.

Comment: I have worked as a bicycle mechanic for so long if I wrote an answer to reflect all of the dumb stuff I have seen people do it would be a master's length thesis every time

Comment: regarding the comment about getting a good deal the olive and inserts are like 4-7$ usd.  To me that is a horrible ROI for the thought that your brakes might stop working in traffic or the forest and you hit something immovable like a tree or car

Answer (score 2):

When i look in my catalogue at aftermarket hoses and connectors (perhaps from Elvedes), the main factor with olive and barb compatibility is mostly relating to the hose, in instances where the compression nut is basically the same size.

So to avoid problems, you use the olive and barb suitable for the hose you wish to use. Where you are certain the outer diameter and the inner diameter match your olive and barb, the likelyhood is that you can get a good seal. The main concern is that you will get a leak when testing straight away and have wasted time and money on the "wrong" parts. If the hose is held fast by the olive it is unlikely to fail catastrophically and unexpectedly after not doing that when you sqeeze hard looking for leaks. I hope you see what you mean there.

My opinion is that it isn't worth doing unless the parts you need are totally unavailable because you waste all the time fitting up and bleeding, and all the money on fittings if it doesn't work perfectly. It's a gamble that most people can't be bothered with!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wondering. YES, you can. Been riding my Zee:s with the red Sram Olive for a summer now without any issues at all. As I prefer the way the Sram olives connects with the hose, this is how I will be running all my Shimanos in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I have got a lot of shimano pins and olives here and now i switched to sram/avid HRD (Hydro road) - the prices for these olives/hoses/sets are ridicilous. So I had good look at both. shimano (brass-) olive and (stainless-) pin should work absolutely fine on sram/avid hoses. The cone of the housing/screw that actually presses the Olive onto the hose are the same (Diameter of the hose also). 
This only accounts for the standard (silver aluminium - black pin) avid/sram hose olive. These Red ones "stelamajjig" or whatever (i only know of etap road) - i have these here - are a bit different but i don t have the corresponding etap levers. Somwhere someone wrote that these may press a valve when mounted - with the standard ones these valves would stay closed. regards from berlin

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Used Shimano specific olive pins on my Avid Elixir 5 and Sram DB5 with no problems at all.... Been using them for about half a year now. Still holding strong. No leaks at all

Comment: olive pins? can you clarify if you mean olives, or connector inserts, or both?

Comment: Thanks, I also have Zees, I will try next time with the SRAM oliver and barb. The Shimano olive and barb system is such a hit and miss to install, even on the factory assembled brake, the olive was not seated properly. I have already ruined a brake lever because the olive was not seated well, and I overtightened. I really prefer the SRAM system with the threads.